# How to install Structorizer on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

How can I install [this Structorizer](http://structorizer.fisch.lu/)?

Please describe me extensive because I am a Ubuntu-Beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download .deb package [here](https://people.debian.org/~debalance/structorizer/current/structorizer_3.22-2_all.deb)

Open terminal and run the following commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo su
dpkg -i structorizer_3.22-2_all.deb
apt-get install -f
```

The first step might fail due to missing dependencies. The second step will install these dependencies and then complete the installation.

[image: Imgur]